# Get a more precise timer in python

Tags: python, timer, precision, milliseconds

Given this example code:

```
start = time.clock()

while (abs(x**2 - userInput) > epsilon):

    x = 0.5 * (x + (userInput/x))
    count = count+1

end = time.clock()

print(end-start)
```

And given that this operation, take very little time, how can I get a more precise timer?

I have looked at `timeit` module but could not figure out how to use it or whether it is what I want.

Comment: The complete code is here http://pastie.org/1711210 just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using timeit is simple. A Timer instance takes two strings, the first containing the operations to time, and the second containing setup operations that are performed once before timing begins. The following code should work, just change the variable values to whatever you want.

```
import math
import time
from timeit import Timer

userInput = "0"

while not userInput.isdigit() or int(userInput) <= 0:

    userInput = input("Calcular la raiz de: ") #Get input from user (userInput)

userInput = int(userInput)

epsilon = 0.000001
x=1
count=0

setup = 'from __main__ import userInput, epsilon, x, count'

operations = '''
x = 1
count = 0
while (abs(x**2 - userInput) > epsilon):

    x = 0.5 * (x + (userInput/x))
    count = count+1
'''

print('The operations took %.4f microseconds.' % Timer(operations, setup).timeit(1))

#run the operations again to get the x and count values
x = 1
count = 0
while (abs(x**2 - userInput) > epsilon):

    x = 0.5 * (x + (userInput/x))
    count = count+1
print("La raíz de", userInput, "es:",x,"implicó",count,"intentos")
```

This will run your code a default of one million times and return the total time in seconds it took to run. You can run it a different number of times by passing a number into `timeit()`.

Comment: I can't understand what goes inside `op = '''`

Comment: That would be all of the code you want to time. The string that you pass to Timer can't reference any variables outside of the string, so you will have to define everything inside it. If you give me the values you use for `x`, `userInput` and `epsilon`, I can give you a more complete example.

Comment: @Narcolei: so if I want to time this while loop ti should be between `'`?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it more complete. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I can has code :) http://pastie.org/1711210 how would you do it in this particular cas, sorry to bother! I can't seem to figure out what needs to be a string.

Comment: Here you go: a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't compared this way to timeit but sometimes i use datetime subtractions for quick and dirty timing. I'll run some tests when i get home and compare.

```
import datetime

x = 1
count = 0
userInput = 1
epsilon = 1

start = datetime.datetime.now()

while (abs(x**2 - userInput) > epsilon):
    x = 0.5 * (x + (userInput/x))
    count = count+1

print datetime.datetime.now() - start, "s"
```

results in:

```
0:00:00.000011 s
```